# can you store a value in a gitlab pipeline so that later piplines can acces it?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a versioning system that is automatically increased every time a commit is pushed to the master branch. I created an enviroment varible through Settings->CI/CD->Environment variables and attempted to increment it using the following code:

```py
   old_version = os.environ["SEMVER_VERSION"]
   new_version = bump(old_version)
   os.environ["SEMVER_VERSION"] = new_version
```

The problem is that these changes are only made to a local copy of the environment variable that is discarded when the pipeline is finished. So my question is if there is any way to store a value so that all  pipelines can acces it and change it?

A common solution to this appears to be to store the value in git tags or a file that is then pushed back to the git repository, the tutorial I followed did this https://threedots.tech/post/automatic-semantic-versioning-in-gitlab-ci/, but i can't programmatically push commits due to restrictions on the self-hosted gitlab server that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the same variable with the new value using the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable) :

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \ 
"https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables/SEMVER_VERSION" \ 
--form "value=$new_version"
```